# Better way to detect HashMap contains the same List or not

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I have a `List` which will be changed overtime and I want to store it with a time value and check if the same `List` appears again.

ex:

```
[1, 2, 3] is same as [1, 2, 3]
```

I thought that since `List<Integer>` is passed by the reference value, so I think the key should be stringified to be used.

E.g.:

```
Map<String, Integer> = new HashMap<>()
(key:"stringified key", value: .....)
```

But I find that `Map<List<Integer>, Integer> map = new HashMap<>()` also works but I don't know why it works, since the key should be reference to the same list no matter what the values in list changed.

E.g.:

```
(key:[reference to key], value: .....)
List<Integer> testList = new ArrayList<>();
testList.add(0);
map.put(testList, 0);
testList.set(0, 1);
if(map.containsKey(testList))System.out.println("duplicate");
else System.out.println("unique");
```

The above result will print "unique" but I think it should print "duplicate".
Why does the above result show this?

Comment: Never modify a key object in a map. Unpredictable behaviour is for certain. Instead remove the mapping, modify the key and reinsert. The reason you get *unique* in this case is that the hashcode of the list has changed, so the hash map cannot find it even though it is in there, only now stored under the wrong hash value. Or instead you *might* perhaps wrap your list in an object the hashcode of whoch doesn’t depend in the list, but this would be ugly and hard to maintain. so I recommend you don’t.

Comment: ... the last line of the code block `else System.out.println("unique);` is missing quotation marks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since yoy changed the content of the `ArrayList` the value of the `ArrayList` `hashCode` also changed.

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add(0); 
System.out.println(l.hashCode()); // 31
l.set(0, 1);
System.out.println(l.hashCode()); // 32
```

This goes against the principle of `HashMap` where the `hashCode` is used to find the element's location. Objects used for the `HashMap` keys should have constant `hashCode`, otherwise the `HashMap` lookup logic won't work.

Comment: is this kind of bug? since hashcode in updated for `ArrayList` but not in the hash  bucket

Comment: @Deadpool `HashMap` uses `hashCode` value to select the bucket on insertion. If different `hashCode` is used during lookup it will look into different bucket and won't find the value.